# Pointer to the same instance used in a different class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, instance

How to solve this situation: I have three classes, to call them `A`, `B` and `C`. In `C` I have members of `A` and `B`. How do I set a pointer in `B` to have the same instance from `C` to `A` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
  int x; // no init, random to can test
  A() {
    printf("From A, x=%d\n", x);
  }
  void getP(A *ptr) {
    ptr = this;
  }
};

class B {
public:
  A *a;
  B() {
    a->getP(a);
    printf("From B, x=%d\n", a->x);
  }
  void test() {
    printf("From test(), x=%d\n", a->x);
  }
};

class C {
public:
  A a; B b;
  C() {
    a.x=55;
    printf("From C, x=%d\n", a.x);
    b.test();
  }
};

int main () {
  C c;

  return 0;
}
```

In this test, the values are different, is not the same instance, I want to have 55 result in *From `test()`* . How to make this?

Comment: Problem solved:  b.a=&a; in C. Must set instance in C not in B ! But still do not understand why not works on the first code ?

Comment: See my answer. You can actually have `B` handle it by modifying its constructor.

Comment: Also your code contains UB in `B`'s constructor - dereferencing uninitialized `a`.

Comment: BTW - the `getP` is getting `ptr` by value, and therefore does **not** update the pointer passed by the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issues in you code:**

Your current code has UB ([undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) in this line in `B` constructor:

```
a->getP(a);
```

This is because `a` is not initialized at this point and therefore it is UB to dereference it (with `->`).

In addition, `A::getP(A *ptr)` is getting `ptr` by value, and therefore it does not update the pointer from the caller.
In order to do so you need to get it by reference (`void getP(A * & ptr)`). However it is not needed at all - see below.

**Solution:**

In order to achieve what you want, you can add a `A*` parameter to the constructor of `B`, that will be used to initialized `B::a` member.
Then pass the address of `C::a` member, when `B` is constructed from `C`'s constructor.

There is also no need for `A::getP` anymore.

Below is your complete example with this modification.
*(the changes are marked with "VVVV")*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
    int x{ 0 };
    A() {
        printf("From A, x=%d\n", x);
    }
};

class B {
public:
    A* a;
//----VVVVVV----VVVV---
    B(A * a_) : a(a_) {
        printf("From B, x=%d\n", a->x);
    }
    void test() {
        printf("From test(), x=%d\n", a->x);
    }
};

class C {
public:
    A a; B b;
//--------VVVVV--
    C() : b(&a) {
        a.x = 55;
        printf("From C, x=%d\n", a.x);
        b.test();
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
From A, x=0
From B, x=0
From C, x=55
From test(), x=55
```

Note that it's not a good practice to have uninitialized data, and therefore I initialized `A::x` to 0.